# Rotate on hover with transition makes quality low?

Tags: html, css, rotation, css-transitions, transform

Alright, first of all - i'm not sure the title was very well explained...

This is what i've got:

```css
#bookknap {
 background-color: #e9533b;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 color: white;
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 text-align:center;
 transform:rotate(22.5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(22.5deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(22.5deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out; /* Animeret rotate */
 font-family:Roboto;
 font-size:1em;
 text-transform:uppercase;
}

#bookknap:hover {
  transform:none;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out; /* Animeret rotate */
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
  <div id="bookknap">Book et møde</div>
```

When i hover the button, the text quality is lowered while in transition? Why, and can it be fixed?

Should be mentioned that i want to do this using only HTML and CSS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Modify the property `transform` on both states of the button to include the value `translate3d(0, 0, 0)`;

This should make the text look more smooth between states.

**Update:**

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ahm7777/aw2nubqs/2/) is a JSFiddle with the working code, I also added another property called `-webkit-font-smoothing`, which handles how WebKit render the font. This leads to a barely perceptible change, but that helps a lot with the smooth look of the letters.

Comment: I tried this - although i might do it wrong, but when i do it - it wont even transform anymore?

https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @CarstenAndersen, updated answer with a fiddle for you

Comment: Thanks - seems great. Although the problem i had, doesnt occur while using my MacBook? Still on Chrome. 
Will use it though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but the `border-radius: 50%` is causing the text to transform during the rotation. This also happens if you use `clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%)` to make a circle.